# Compressing music files to fit a given size

Tags: compression, mp3, music

I have a few thousand mp3 files on my pc of different quality (total 10gb). I'd like to compress all of them to fit my smart watch which has 4gb storage.

Are there any tools to compress all of them using the total size of all the files as a target?

Comment: MP3 is already compressed and the only way to reduce the file size is to convert to a lower bitrate (and consequently more loss = less audio quality).

Comment: Quality wouldn't matter too much. I'd be using bone conduction headphone when exercising with smartwatch

Comment: It’s just math. A few thousand MP3s will be a some hundreds of hours of music. The only way to squeeze those into 4 GB of storage (probably even less anyway) is to compress them to barely above analog phone quality. You then use the bitrate and configure your favorite batch MP3 converter, that’s it.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from 'product requests' being off-topic…

You're kind of asking for a tool no-one really wants. Compressing an entire library to a specific size, especially with such a **massive** data reduction, is just not common-enough for people to really want it <sup>[1]</sup>. There's also the issue that to achieve this, you first have to recompress them all & see where you end up, rinse & repeat until it fits. You can't really guess what will happen in such detail with an mp3 until you do it, or at least do part of it & extrapolate.

You didn't specify the more important data-points [existing bit-rates & number of files], so we'll have to guess.
If your files are all 320kbps, then 128 will still be absolutely fine for a portable device<sup>[2]</sup> [so much so that most people would literally not be able to tell the difference], but if they're already at 128, then no-one's really going to want them at 1/3 of that size. You could get away with 96k mono & get somewhere close, but tbh, I'd just pick fewer tunes.
How long are you going to be listening? 6 weeks?

<sup>[1]</sup> … or sensible enough for anyone to consider making it ;)

<sup>[2]</sup> If you're in the Apple ecosystem, there's already a simple check box in iTunes or the newer 'Music' app that will do this on the fly for you at each sync. There's also an option to just "fill the device with a random selection"

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of online tools that can do this. I have tried https://www.freeconvert.com/mp3-compressor and it seems easy and fast to use.

Check it out.

Comment: I have 10gb of mp3 files though. The online tool you posted only allow using size of individual file as target not the total size of 1000s of files.

Comment: That is a lot of files. How about Monkey’s Audio: https://monkeysaudio.com/index.html maybe that will work better.